# Hide/show tab as per API response

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

I have created static tabs in tabbar. But my requirement is to set the tab as data available in the API response. eg. if there are animal data in API then only I need to show animal tab and likewise.
I am using getx for this.
So how to show/hide the tab?

here's my code:

```
 Container(
                color: ColorConstants.secondaryBlue,
                child: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                  labelColor: ColorConstants.app_sky1,
                  tabs:controller.myTabs,
                  controller: controller.tabController,
                  indicatorColor: ColorConstants.app_sky1,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                ),
              ),
```

and the code from the controller

```
class DetailController extends BaseController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin { late TabController tabController ;
 @override
void onInit() async {
  bool connectionResult = await Utility.isConnected();
  if (connectionResult) {
    isLoading(true);

    Webservice().loadqueryParamGet(DetailApi).then((model) => {},);
    Webservice().loadqueryParamGet(EditionApi).then((model) => {},);

  } else {
    Utility.showToast('No internet');
  }

  super.onInit();
  tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
}

 final List<Tab> myTabs = const <Tab>[

Tab(text: AppConstants.about),
Tab(text: AppConstants.edition),
Tab(text: AppConstants.bundledIn),
Tab(text: AppConstants.ports),
Tab(text: AppConstants.masters),  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

this similar problem i was faced ,
i get data from api and search field but as per data i have to maintain three tab and this is same as you faced. sometime need to hide(remove) tab and sometime need to show(add) tab

this will do when i search something inside search-field

and i do this way
first i take empty tab list like

```
  TabController? tabController;
  List<String> tabList = [];

    TextEditingController txtSearch = TextEditingController();
  TabController? tabController;
  final paBusinessController = Get.find<PABusinessController>();
  List<CompanyWithMember> searchCompanyList = [];
  List<BusinessMember> searchMemberList = [];
  List<BusinessSearchModel> searchCategoryList = [];
```

and inside initState

i just assign value (possible three tab name will get)

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    iniValue();
  }



  iniValue() {
    tabList = [
      "Members",
      "Companies",
      "Categories",
    ];
    tabController = TabController(length: tabList.length, vsync: this);
    searchCategoryList.addAll(paBusinessController.businessSearchList);
    for (int i = 0; i < paBusinessController.businessSearchList.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0;
          j < paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company.length;
          j++) {
        searchCompanyList.add(
          paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company[j],
        );

        if (paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company[j].member !=
            null) {
          if (!searchMemberList.contains(
              paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company[j].member)) {
            searchMemberList.add(
              paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company[j].member!,
            );
          }
        }
        if (j > 20) {
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

here inside initState i just assign tabController values

Note : Here inside iniValue() function the logic is as i needed your will be not same as per requirement

```
  void search(String value) {
    if (value.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        isSearching = true;
        searchCompanyList.clear();
        searchMemberList.clear();
        searchCategoryList.clear();
        tabList.clear();
      });
      for (int i = 0; i < paBusinessController.businessSearchList.length; i++) {
        for (final company
            in paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].company) {
          if (company.companyName.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
            searchCompanyList.add(company);
          }
          if (company.member != null) {
            final name = wholeName(
                    prefix: company.member?.masterMember.prefix,
                    fName: company.member?.masterMember.firstName,
                    lName: company.member?.masterMember.lastName)
                .toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
              if (searchMemberList
                  .every((element) => element.id != company.member?.id)) {
                searchMemberList.add(company.member!);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        final categoryName =
            paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
          searchCategoryList.add(paBusinessController.businessSearchList[i]);
        }
      }

      // if (searchMemberList.isNotEmpty) {
      //   tabList.add("Members");
      // }
      // if (searchCompanyList.isNotEmpty) {
      //   tabList.add("Companies");
      // }
      // if (searchCategoryList.isNotEmpty) {
      //   tabList.add("Categories");
      // }

      if (searchCompanyList.isEmpty && tabList.contains("Companies")) {
        tabList.remove("Companies");
      } else if (searchCompanyList.isNotEmpty &&
          !tabList.contains("Companies")) {
        tabList.add("Companies");
      }
      
      if (searchMemberList.isEmpty && tabList.contains("Members")) {
        tabList.remove("Members");
      } else if (searchMemberList.isNotEmpty && !tabList.contains("Members")) {
        tabList.add("Members");
      }
      
      if (searchCategoryList.isEmpty && tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.remove("Categories");
      } else if (searchCategoryList.isNotEmpty &&
          !tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.add("Categories");
      }
      
      if (tabList.isNotEmpty &&
          tabList.contains("Members") &&
          tabList.contains("Companies") &&
          !tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.clear();
        tabList.add("Members");
        tabList.add("Companies");
      }
      
      if (tabList.isNotEmpty &&
          tabList.contains("Members") &&
          !tabList.contains("Companies") &&
          tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.clear();
        tabList.add("Members");
        tabList.add("Categories");
      }
      
      if (tabList.isNotEmpty &&
          !tabList.contains("Members") &&
          tabList.contains("Companies") &&
          tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.clear();
        tabList.add("Companies");
        tabList.add("Categories");
      }
      
      if (tabList.isNotEmpty &&
          tabList.contains("Members") &&
          tabList.contains("Companies") &&
          tabList.contains("Categories")) {
        tabList.clear();
        tabList.add("Members");
        tabList.add("Companies");
        tabList.add("Categories");
      }

      tabController = TabController(length: tabList.length, vsync: this);
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      setState(() {
        searchCompanyList.clear();
        searchMemberList.clear();
        searchCategoryList.clear();
        isSearching = false;
      });

      iniValue();
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    }
  }
```

l called search() function inside onChange : (value){} property of textFormField.

each time i first clean tabList, and identify what i need in tab so that,

i just add each-time in tabList as per data i get and at end of this i just reassign controller value like

```
 tabController = TabController(length: tabList.length, vsync: this);
      setState(() {});
```

and i will work fine, don't forget to assign controller in tab and TabBarView widget

show code

```
// inside Scaffold
// body : 

   body: Obx(
        () {
          final isLoading =
              paBusinessController.isLoadingForBusinessSearch.isTrue;
          if (isLoading) {
            return const LoadingComponent();
          } else if (isSearching && dataFound) {
            return const LabelComponent(label: "No data found for this search");
          }

          return tabList.isEmpty
              ? const ErrorPageComponent(
                  title: 'No Result Found',
                  content:
                      "Search by member name, company name or category no any result found",
                  image:
                      "assets/images/empty_data_component/search not found.svg",
                )
              : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3, top: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
                        child: TabBar(
                          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                          controller: tabController,
                          labelPadding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                          unselectedLabelColor: grey400,
                          labelColor: appPrimary,
                          labelStyle: MyTextStyles.semiBold.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 13.5,
                            color: appPrimary,
                            letterSpacing: 0.3,
                          ),
                          unselectedLabelStyle: MyTextStyles.medium.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 13.5,
                          ),
                          isScrollable: true,
                          indicator: const BubbleTabIndicator(
                            indicatorHeight: 40,
                            indicatorColor: appPrimaryLight,
                            tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                            indicatorRadius: 8,
                          ),
                          tabs: tabList.map((e) {
                            return Container(
                              height: 40,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 15,
                                vertical: 10,
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: appPrimaryLight,
                                  width: 1.2,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  e,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 12, right: 12, top: 10),
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: tabController,
                            children: tabView(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
        },
      ),
```

and tabView() is below

```
  List<Widget> tabView() {
    return [
      if (tabList.contains('Members')) MemberList(memberList: searchMemberList),
      if (tabList.contains('Companies'))
        CompanyList(companyList: searchCompanyList),
      if (tabList.contains("Categories"))
        CategoryList(searchCategoryList: searchCategoryList),
    ];
  }
}
```

hope this will little help you

thank you